# React hook stuck on previous object value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have a list of objects I am creating and updating with useState:

```
{
        id: list1.length + 1,
        key: list1.length + 1,
        variable: userInput.variable,
        name: userInput.name,
        value: userInput.value,
}
```

When I set the value of name: to "text", the value changes and updates to "variable", which is a value that has been previously and commonly used. When I looked through the Chrome debugger the value never changed and was correct, "text", however, when I console.log() the value it shows me "variable". Another strange thing is that after I add an item to this list of objects, the debugger will show a changed value in name: for the previous items in the list.

The biggest kicker is that I went through all my code and hard coded in "text" into the value for name: and guess what? It still shows as "variable". Is there some sort of cache in React? Or maybe there is a bug?

Comment: Can you share your code ? because i want to see what you declare state variable name of input may be you are using wrong variable name here

Comment: Per my answer on this thread, I already solved the issue. An "if" statement in the code was reassigning the variable.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I just needed to post on Stack Overflow to finally solve the issue. I have an if statement

```
        {itemsList.map((item) => {
          if ((item.name = "variable")) {
```

And it was functioning as both an if statement and an assignment operator because I forgot to put in the second set of = .